# Running threads in parallel, seems to be causing an infinite loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

It seems that if a given thread fails for any reason, this will cause an infinite loop.

This is code that isn't written by me so I can't even edit it, **but I think the most obvious problem here is that the counter variable `totalActions` isn't marked as volatile,** and as a result the threads are not seeing the most up-to-date value.

So it looks like if it never gets the real value of `totalActions`, it will keep waiting?

Will this cause the thread to run recursively then? While debugging, I notice that the executing thread fails (exception is thrown), and it just keeps getting called over and over and over....

```
public void PerformActions(List<Action> actions)
{
   object actionLock = new object();
   int totalActions = actionts.Count;

   for(int x = 0; x < accounts.Count; x++)
   {
      int y = x;
      new Thread(delegate()
      {
        actions[y].Invoke();

        if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref totalActions) == 0)
        {
            lock(actionLock)
            {
                Monitor.Pulse(actionLock);
            }
        }
    }).Start();
   }

   lock(actionLock)
   {
        if(totalActions > 0)
        {
           Monitor.Wait(actionLock);
        }    
   }
}
```

**Update**

Usage is like this, where the `myService` is making `httpRequest` calls to grab json requests from an API service.

```
Execute.InParallel(
new Action[]
    {
    () => { abc = myService.DoSomething(); },
    () => { def = myService.DoSomethingElse(); }
    });
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with the TPL (other than the fact that using the TPL would have prevented this incorrect code from being written in the first place.)

Comment: Well according to MSDN docs the use of volatile should be kept to a minimum if used at all. And is mostly there for embeded systems that have very limited memory. They suggest using the `lock` keyword or another one of the locking mechanisms like mutexes and semaphores. Also the use of `Interlocked.Decrement()` prevents that issue in the first place. because that is an atomic action, meaning only one thread can work on it at a time.

Comment: @Nomad101 I know in java, you have to mark the variable in order to guarantee other threads see the value, otherwise local thread copy will be used and that may not be the correct value.

Comment: @user1361315 within C# that is not true. A variable can be seen by any thread that has the inheritance/Permissions to see it.

Comment: @dlev can you comment on what you find is incorrect?

Comment: @user1361315 I haven't looked at the code too carefully; I'm merely stating the obvious: if one of the failure modes of this piece of code results in an infinite loop/hang, it is almost by definition incorrect. That said, one thing that sticks out is that the for loop variable is captured, rather than a local copy, and so it's certainly possible for both threads to see the same value for `x`, and invoke the same function. Also, if the invoked action throws an exception of some kind, then `totalActions` will never be decremented (which is likely the cause of the hangs you see.)

Comment: @dlev Yes I agree on the exceptions issue, not sure I see your captured versus local copy issue.  If the # of actions is 3, it will loop 3 times, and it gets the action based on actions[index].  Not sure how it matters if its captured or local copy? (oh, unless you are referring to the fact that totalActions should be volaitle).

Comment: @dlev ah, I missed that line when writing it, it actually does that (I added variable y in the loop)  But yes the issue now is with exceptions, I replaced with parallel.invoke and not seeing that issue.

Comment: @user1361315 Cool, glad to hear things seem to be working now. I apologize if my initial comment was a tad brusque.

Answer (score 0):

The lock will act as a memory barrier, ensuring that your test `if(totalActions > 0)` reads the current value. I'm not convinced that this code is race-free but the race would at least be very, very unlikely. You'd have a hard time reproducing it.

So the problem is something else not shown here. Can you use the debugger to find out what exactly the threads involved are doing?

You say some threads die due to an unhandled exception. **Maybe the threads exiting early causes the count not to decrement.**

Also, if you can't change the code, what is the point of the question? I'm not sure what to suggest to you.

Comment: usr, thanaks, I gave an example usage, it is these myService calls make api calls and if the endpoint is down, when in debug mode, it just keeps making the same call over and over again i.e. DoSomething()

Comment: I updated the code.  While debugging, I noticed that once my breakpoint hits the Monitor.Wait line, it never actually even reaches the if statement where it decrements.  Is that the cause of the infinite loop?  NOt sure why it would keeping trying to make the httprequest when it is failing...

Answer (score 0):

The loop is incorrect - in that variable x is captured incorrectly. it will always have the last value of x when `actions[x].Invoke();` is executed in each thread. So, the last delegate passed to array will be called multiple times.

Correct way to do it is like this

```
    for(int x = 0; x < accounts.Count; x++)
       {
          int y = x; // here correct value of y will be captured in delegate
          new Thread(delegate()
          {
            actions[y].Invoke();
   ...
```

Comment: sorry the actual code had that, I somehow missed that line sorry!

Comment: OK then best you can do is change the if condition to `if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref totalActions, 0, 0) > 0)`